# Creating a JSON string from jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json

I am creating a generic To-Do list, and I am trying to somehow "save" the list. How it works now is: Each "column" of the table is stored in its separate array, and I loop through the multiple arrays to receive all the data necessary. I know a lot about databases, but I'm not using one because simply, I don't know how to!

In a nutshell, I want to be able to somehow store this list into a JSON string (I heard its easier to work with, and I can parse it), and either save it to my computer so I can load it later, or save it as a cookie. I'm not sure if you can do that, as the max size is 4KB.

Any suggestions would be great!

Please find my code. I've excluded a lot of CSS

HTML

```
<div id="form"><label>Task Number: </label><input value="1" readonly="readonly" id="taskNum" type="text"></div>
 <div id="form"><label>Description: </label><input id="taskDesc" type="text"></div>
<div id="form"><label>Task Name: </label><input id="taskName" type="text"></div>
<div id="form"><label>Date: </label><input id="taskDate" type="text"></div>
<div id="form"><label>Time: </label><input id="taskTime" type="text"></div>
<div id="form"><label>Notes: </label><input id="taskNotes" type="text"></div>
<input id="addTask" value="Add Task" onclick="startTask();" type="button">
```

JavaScript

```
var numA = [];
var descA = [];
var nameA = [];
var dateA = [];
var timeA = [];
var notesA = [];


var num = $('#taskNum');
var desc = $('#taskDesc');
var name = $('#taskName');
var date = $('#taskDate');
var time = $('#taskTime');
var notes = $('#taskNotes');

function startTask()
{

    i=numA.length
    alert(i + ' before adding to array');

    numA[i] = num.val();
    descA[i] = desc.val();
    nameA[i] = name.val();
    dateA[i] = date.val();
    timeA[i] = time.val();
    notesA[i] = notes.val();

    displayTable();
}

function displayTable(){

    var c = -0;
    var newTable = '';

    while ( c<= i)
    {
        var st = '<tr><td>';
        var mid = '</td><td>';
        var del = '<label onclick="deleteRecord('+c+')" style="Color:blue; text-decoration:underline;">Delete Record?</label>';
        var end = '</td></tr>';

        alert('numA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ numA[c] +
         '\n descA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ descA[c] +
         '\n nameA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ nameA[c] +
         '\n dateA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ dateA[c] +
         '\n timeA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ timeA[c] +
         '\n notesA value: ' + c + ' value = '+ notesA[c]);
        newTable = newTable + st + numA[c] + mid + descA[c] + mid + nameA[c] + mid + dateA[c] + mid + timeA[c]+mid+del+end;
        alert(newTable);
        $('#toDoTable').html(newTable);
        c++
    };
```

Comment: have you tried the stringify function?

Comment: can't duplicate ID's in a page..they must be unique by definition. Use class instead

Comment: The purpose of `ID` is to uniquely identify an element in a page, so you should not duplicate them

Comment: Will there be multiple task at a time in the page (The set of element given in the html code)

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the stringify function. I tried looking up other functions but they seemed a little over my head.

Comment: Arun, I'm not sure I understand your question. I'll try and answer it through. There can be multiple tasks on the page, and the array is looped through to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments... change ID to class to avoid duplication.

Suggest wrapping each `task` in an outer wrapper:

```
<div class="task_wrap">
    <div class="form"><label>Task Number: </label><input value="1" readonly="readonly" class="taskNum" type="text"></div>
    <div class="form"><label>Description: </label><input class="taskDesc" type="text"></div>
    <!-- other inputs for task-->
</div>
```

Map to array:

```
var tasklistArray=$('.task_wrap').map( function(){
       var task={};
       $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
             task[ this.className]=$(this).val();
       });
        return task;
 }).get();
```

Change to JSON:

```
var tasklistJSON= JSON.stringify( tasklistArray);
```

If only using this in modern browsers can store this in `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("taskList", tasklistJSON);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rDh4w/

API Reference for map http://api.jquery.com/map/

Comment: Ok wow, a lot is going on in that, haha. I see that it works great, but I don't know how. I've never seen .map before. Would you mind breaking down the code?

Comment: added API reference link for `map`. API is best place to figure your question out